# SyncedSideBar plug-in extention for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

https://github.com/TheSpyder/SyncedSideBar

**SyncedSideBar** is an amazing Sublime Text plugin to sync project sidebar (folder view) with the currently active file.

I just recently explore a new text editor **VS Code**.
I've tried google around for this similar plugin on VS Code. 
I haven't found one yet.

Please let me know if you guys know any VS Code plug-in does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for - click on a editor file tab and the folder it is in is **opened** if necessary in the sidebar and the file highlighted - is the default behavior of vscode.  If that isn't working for you perhaps reset this setting to true:

> // Controls if the explorer should automatically reveal and select files when opening them.
>
> ```
>  "explorer.autoReveal": true,
> ```

Comment: Ok. let me try that. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Adding it to my user settings - work on the first try. (y)